# Issue with initializing COM object

Tags: c++, windows, vb.net, com, com-interop

I compiled the following VB code and got the dll ("TestVB.dll") and tlb ("TestVB.tlb") files as output.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Namespace TesterNS

    <ComVisible(True),
    Guid("4B673F5A-A953-4C20-9A90-8F94ED2F6DDF"),
    InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)>
    Public Interface _Tester
        Function GetMonth() As Integer
    End Interface

    <ComVisible(True),
    Guid("FEC833EE-37E9-4406-9344-8A8BD5C43B07"),
    ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),
    ProgId("Tester.Numbers1")> Public Class Tester
        Implements _Tester

        Public Tester()

        Public Function GetMonth() As Integer Implements _Tester.GetMonth
            GetMonth = DateTime.Now.Month
        End Function
    End Class

End Namespace
```

I selected the

> Register for COM interop

option in the project settings for the VB project.

I am trying to access the above functionality from a C++ code. 
I included the following import statement in the stdafx.h file in C++.

```
#import "TestVB.tlb" no_function_mapping, no_namespace, named_guids
```

and trying to access the COM object as follows:

```
HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
_TesterPtr t1 = NULL;
CLSID cls;
std::string s = "";
bool flag = false;
hr = CLSIDFromProgID(L"Tester.Numbers1", &cls);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = CoCreateInstance(cls, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(_Tester), (void**)&t1);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        s = "success";
    else
        s = "fail";
}
```

I am seeing `hr = REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG Class not registered` error after making the `CoCreateInstance` call.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The "Register for COM-interop" can only provide the 32-bit registration, you must therefore ensure you build the x86 flavor of your C++ project.  Also ensure you run VS elevated so it can write to the registry.  The C++ code cannot work as-is, you must use ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual or ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown to get the Tester interface exposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my C++ application, there is a call to `AfxOleInit()` before `CoInitialize(NULL)`. If I remove the call to `CoInitialize(NULL)`, I was able to get it working.